# My wi fi network is not showing in wi-fi network list

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet, broadcom

Looks strange but my ubuntu 16.04 and then recently installed 18.04 is facing difficulty in connecting to my wi-fi network (router model -DLink DSL 224, service provider- Airtel Broadband, Bangalore). My main concern is I am not able to pin-point the issue like whether its router problem or Ubuntu problem. I have some data points which I would like to share:-

- If the router has issues, then no other devices should be able to connect to it but my smartphones and Windows laptops are doing fine with the router wi-fi.
- if Ubuntu has issues, then no wi-fi signals should be shown for any wi-fi network but it is showing all the neighbor wi-fi signals.
- even if I manually do 'connect to hidden network', sometimes it works and sometimes it does not work.
- sometimes the wi-fi signal shows up on the wi-fi list of Ubuntu.

just for information, My wi-fi hardware is Broadcom limited hardware and I am using Dell Lattitude E5430.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the channel fixed my problem.  To determine which channels are good for you, run this command on Ubuntu:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep Frequency | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

If you encounter an error like "wlan0 doesn't support scanning", then run this command:

```
ifconfig
```

if you can't run `ifconfig` because `net-tools` is not installed, install it with the command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install net-tools
```

look for output - two words wl mine was wlp3s0, so the command would be

```
sudo iwlist wlp3s0 scan | grep Frequency | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

The `sort -n` flag will rank the channels in order of fastest to slowest

Once you've found the best channel,  you change the channel on your router.

then restart your network-manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

You might also want to check if WiFi is blocked - See this related question on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309753/330133)

Comment: You can drop the `wlan0` bit and simply do `sudo iwlist scan` which will do the scan as well.  No need to specify the device directly, which means you will remove almost 50% of your answer and condense it.  No need for `net-tools` or identifying the device, you simply just drop the command in as `sudo iwlist scan | grep Frequency | sort | uniq -c | sort -n` and then keep the router and Network Manager restart bits